# Unable to get ip or hostname

Tags: android, kotlin, ip

I tried to get ip and hostname of different devices on my network using Kotlin and fill a `RecyclerView` with this data, but I couldn't get it going.

I am looking for a certain hostname to return the ip to me like this:

```
val addr = InetAddress.getByName("K50").hostAddress
//val host = addr.hostName
Log.d("console", addr.toString()) 
//Log.d("console", host.toString())
```

Also, I do not understand how to pass the `bytearray` for `InetAddress.getByAddress()`, in order to find the device and its hostname with the ip. Thank you in advance, your help would be invaluable to me since I am a novice.

Update 22/05/20:

```
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val hostname : String  = "google.com"
            try {
                val inet2 = InetAddress.getByName(hostname)
                Log.d("console", inet2.hostAddress.toString())
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.d("console", ex.toString())
            }
        }
```

I had to do it with coroutines because in the main thread it caused me an error, this returns the IP of the hostname that I indicate in the code but, I cannot get it to work with hostname of local devices by wifi only with the dns of web pages.

Comment: Are you looking to get the IP of a specific device.  A device in which you know the device name?  Or are you trying to get a list of all devices (hostnames & IPs) that are on the network?

Comment: hi tom, sorry if this that I write is poorly translated, is that google has helped me. I would need to get the devices just by knowing the beginning of the name, for example: xyz *, that is, all that start with xyz, returning their full name and ip. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you had any success getting names in general? or have you not been able to get any info on devices as of now.

Comment: hi tom, thanks again, yes, I have been able to do something, now I update the question